# Storing and comparing byte values in C

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno setup with a MFRC522 RFID Receiver module. I am attempting to create a verification system in which I use the UID of the card to turn on an L.E.D.
Here is my current code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
    Serial.println("Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
}

void loop() {
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    byte readCard[7] ;
    byte cardCode[7] = E05E987;

Serial.println("Scanned PICC's UID:");
for (int i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
    Serial.print(readCard[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println("");


  if (readCard == cardCode){
    Serial.println("Correct Code");
    return;
    }
}
```

However, When I compile this code I am met with this error:

```
/root/Arduino/RFID_Check_/RFID_Check_.ino: In function 'void loop()':
RFID_Check_:28: error: 'E05E987' was not declared in this scope
     byte cardCode[7] = E05E987;
                        ^
exit status 1
'E05E987' was not declared in this scope
```

How can  resolve this error? I have tried changing the values inbetween he square brackets to no avail.

Comment: What is it that line of code intedned to do?

Comment: Where did you get this `E05E987` symbol from? Do you expect it to have been defined or declared by MFRC522.h? I did a Google search of that symbol and found nothing relevant...

Comment: Initialising a byte-array like this `byte cardCode[7] = <multi-byte-literal>;` looks plain wrong to me.

Comment: ... and comparing arrays like this `if (readCard == cardCode){` as well.

Comment: the E05E997 is the UID of the PICC card

Comment: @alk how would I go about comparing arrays? I'm sorry but I'm new to C programming, I have more experience in C# However

Comment: Either compare element by element or if the same size and all elements are used and no `struct`s or `union`s are involved use `memcmp()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decare an array of 7 bytes. It seems you want to assign it a value; however, the value isn't appropriate for a byte.

To assign a hexadecimal value, you must precede it with `0x` so `0xE05E987` would be a proper hexadecimal value.

But that value is too large for a byte. You can assign the values to the array as follows:

```
byte cardCode[7] = {0xE0, 0x5E, 0x98, 0x07};
```

Any value not provided will be zero. The above has initialized `cardCode[0]` through `cardCode[3]` and has set the remainder to zero.

Comment: Mind the endianness.

Comment: I tried this out and it corrected the error, however the if/else statement at the end still returns false. I've attempted to print the array to no avail...

Comment: The `==` comparisson operator cannot compare arays. It can only compare elements. So you must write a loop, comparing each byte of one array with the corresponding byte of the other array: `for (int i=0; i<7;i++) if (readCard[i]!=cardCode[i]) break; //not equal`